# How to update status of Parent sate using functional component react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I am using 2 useState in my code. When 2nd useSate status is true I want 1st useState status to be made false.

I can achieve it using class components not via functional component.

**Class Component Code**

```
 class App extends React.Component {
 state = { visible: false, childrenDrawer: false };

showDrawer = () => {
this.setState({
  visible: true,
});
};

onClose = () => {
this.setState({
  visible: false,
});
};

showChildrenDrawer = () => {
this.setState({
  childrenDrawer: true,
  visible: false, //**this make 1st state status false when 2nd state is true**
});
};

onChildrenDrawerClose = () => {
this.setState({
  childrenDrawer: false,
});
};
```

How I can achieve this in the functional component please guide

```
 const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
 const [hideAuto, setAuto]= useState(false);

 const showDrawer = () => {
 setVisible(true);
 };

const onClose = () => {
setVisible(false);
};

const Quality=()=>{
setAuto(true);
}

const Selection = () => {
setVisible(false);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize and update state in function components using React hooks just like you would in your class.

In your functional component, why are you using two separate hooks? Why not just track state like you did in your class, ie. using a single object. For example:

```
let [myState, updateMyState] = useState({ visible: false, childrenDrawer: false });
```

Then to update the state:

```
updateMyState(...myState, visible: true) // show drawer for example
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this simple setup, where you pass the function that changes parent state as props to the child component:

```
const parentDrawer = () => {
    const [parentState, setParentState] = useState(true);
    const onChildClose = () => {
        setParentState(false)
    }
    return <childDrawer onChildClose={onChildClose} />
}

const childDrawer = ({ onChildClose }) => {
    const onChildInteraction = () => {
        onChildClose()
    }
    return (...)
}
```

This covers the case in which the child is rendered/returned by the parent. If you have them separately, maybe look into context.